# How to count all holidays between two dates, excluding those that fall on a weekend - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am able to count the amount of holidays between two dates like this:

```
=COUNTIFS($T$47:$T$57,">="&F59,$T$47:$T$57,"<="&G59)
```

The values $T$47:$T$57 are the cells in which my holiday dates are located. F59 is the start date. G59 is the end date.

So basically what this does is count how many times my holidays occur within the start and end date

**--e.g.--** *start date = 11/24/2016, end date = 11/30/2016 returns 2 (Thanksgiving & Black Friday, which fall on Thursday and Friday).*

However, when it comes down to something like Christmas of this year, I am having trouble. Christmas Eve, Christmas Day, and the day after Christmas are counted as holidays but occur on Saturday, Sunday, & Monday, respectively. I don't want to count holidays that fall on a weekend, so my desired return would be 1. However, using my formula, I am currently getting returned 3.

How do I exclude weekends within this problem?

Let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: is it allowed to ad a column next to $T to represent the weekday of the date as a figure between 1 and 7?

Comment: Have you considered incorporating the [Weekday](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/WEEKDAY-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a) formula into your table? Using the formula =MOD(WEEKDAY(cell), 7) < 2 will return a TRUE/FALSE statement for you (with True being that the day falls on a weekend.)

Comment: @MikeD That shouldn't be a problem. However, since my dates are a formula themselves instead of hard-coded dates, they would need to correspond with that. New Year Day is like this '=DATE(T46,1,1)' and Labor day like this '=DATE(T46,9,1)+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(T46,9,1)),1,0,6,5,4,3,2)'

Comment: @Clusks I have tried weekday but wasn't sure how to go about it. I needed to return a number value instead of boolean. How would I go about making each day true/false without having a large list of Thursday=TRUE, Friday=TRUE, Saturday=FALSE, etc. That was my dilemma.

Comment: count all dates falling on weekdays SAT/SUN via WEEKDAY() values and subtract this from your gross count ...

Comment: @MikeD So using WEEKDAY(), I can specify it to only count weekends? So I could probably get WEEKDAY() to return 1 or 7 and if they do, I could -1 for each 1 or 7 listed from total holiday count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to add a weekday number (in example I used `=WEEKDAY(date, 2)` with SAT/SUN being numbers 6 & 7, respectively (just to please my convention of starting a week on Monday).

Furthermore I used 4 and'ed conditions, the first 2 dealing with start & end date from column B - like you had it, the 2nd two eliminating (from the new range in column C) weekdays with numbers 6 & 7.

[image]

Should work for your list as well ...

Other options include to create an array formula or a sumproduct of 1 times a conditional (1 or 0 - depending on weekday)

Comment: This seems to be what I need. Right now, I'm just trying to integrate it into my formula. How does that formula know to take &6 and &7 from WEEKDAY()? _ps I gave you an upvote, but it doesn't show since I have low reputation points. I'm pretty new to StackOverflow. I'll be sure to help someone else, just as you have helped me. Thanks!_

Comment: look at conditions #3 and 4 of the (new) countifs ... weekdayrange,"<>"&6,weekdayrange,"<>"&7 will suppress SATs and SUNs ... and if you think you like this answer bst, please accept it ... it will also give you a bounty and more rep

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be accomplished with the [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48E717BF-A7A3-495F-969E-5005E3EB18E7) or [NETWORKDAYS.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28)  function by subtracting one with holidays specified from one without.

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A2, B2)-NETWORKDAYS(A2, B2, $Z$2:$Z$6)
```

[image: networkdays_intl_elapsed_2]

The `$Z$2:$Z$6` range of holidays could be made dynamic by creating a named range called `holidays` with a *Refers to:* of,

```
=Sheet1!Z2:INDEX(Sheet1!Z:Z, MATCH(1e99, Sheet1!Z:Z))
```

Use as,

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A2, B2)-NETWORKDAYS(A2, B2, holidays)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following *UDF()*

```
Public Function KountHolidays(Hlist As Range, fDate As Date, lDate As Date) As Long
    Dim d As Date
    For d = fDate To lDate
        ds = Format(d, "dddd")
        If ds <> "Sunday" And ds <> "Saturday" Then
            For Each r In Hlist
                If r.Value = d Then
                    KountHolidays = KountHolidays + 1
                End If
            Next r
        End If
    Next d
End Function
```

For completely arbitrary holidays:

[image]

The neat thing about this approach is that you can easily adapt this to multiple years.